# Hide default values on VC editor

Tags: visual-editor

When I created custom fields on WPBakery (formerly Visual Composer) I have the option 'admin_label' and by default is false but the values always printing on editor.

How to hide the default values only setting the title for block?

[image: Default sample after inserted or updated]

Comment: 3rd party plugin questions are considered off topic here. Have you tried contacting through their official support channels?

Comment: I'll do. Thanks